# How to access the elements by index number from a list of intervals?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, intervals

I encountered this while solving a data structures problem, which says
given a list of intervals: a = [(1,4),(3,5),(4,8)]
Here (1,4) means an interval of numbers from 1 to 4.

How do I access the elements using their index numbers from this list?

a[i][j] doesn't work for me.

Edit: found the solution (python), in case anyone else is looking for the same:

```
a = [(1,4),(2,6),(9,11)]

for i in range(len(a)):
    #to print first number from the interval
    print(a[i][0])
    #to print second number from the interval
    print(a[i][1])
```

Comment: try a[0] which gives (1,4) then a[1] which gives (3,5) and so on

Comment: @iamINDIAN. how do I access individual elements from (1,4)?

Comment: print (a[0][0])
print (a[0][1])

Comment: a[0][0] to get 1 and a[0][1] to get 4 (1st and 2nd coordinate)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [(1,4),(3,5),(4,8)]
for interval in a:
    for each in interval:
        print(each)
```